# 500 errors after deploying CakePHP app to a live web server

Tags: cakephp

I've been developing a cakephp app (2.2) on my local machine using wamp. I'm now at the stage where I want to put it online but all I get is 500 internal server errors. Heres what I've done so far:

1. Created the db on the new web host (exported from my local DB) and imported the details.
2. FTP'd up the contents of the project to the web servers root dir.
3. Changed the db config file to the new db details.
4. visited the url and got "500 Internal server error".

I searched online for a long time trying to get an answer and found various blog articles saying add a leading slash to some of the entries in .htaccess. This didn't work.

I've also deleted any files in /App/tmp/cache and made sure it had the permission 777.

Please can anyone help, I've tried this on both 1and1s shared hosting and another companies shared hosting. Surely there must be a way, what am I missing?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: 1. what errors do U get exacly?
2. try to deploy pure (out of the box) cakePHP first, then add your models ony by one...

Comment: Do you configure mod_rewrite correctly? is it install at all?

Comment: @grzegorz_motyl I get :
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webadmin@kundenserver.de and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
I've tried a clean cake install then uploaded my whole App directory.

Comment: clean cake install works without problem ? It would be most helpful to read server error log...

Comment: @grzegorz_motyl Well the welcome page works and it confirms its connected to the db etc. I'll try adding folders from my /app folder one by one. Cant seem to get the server logs from 1and1. Should I check if mod_rewrite is switched on - how can I do that on share hosting?

Comment: @ArashMousavi I'm on shared hosting so I cant configure it but it does work ok for other non cake sites under this hosting. Is there a way to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploy clean cakePHP first, if it works, try to add models first, one by one. Views should do no harm, so put them after models, next step would be controllers. This way you can establish borken model or controller....

Comment: Just done this, the issue seems to lie with one of my controllers breaking everything (alls ok before I upload that). Problem is, its the controller thats the main part of my app. It works fine locally - what wpould be the next step in tracking down the issue? Thanks again

Comment: add controllers one by one, when the server error appears and you know the broken controller try to comment all his functions, then uncoment them step by step ... and hopefully you can find part of code that trigger server error

Comment: Ok, I've done that - seems to by my index() on my ExpensClaimController. However, its pretty standard code, even if I comment it out it breaks (just having an empty index()). This is what was in it

public function index() {
  $this->set('currentUsersClaims', $this->paginate('ExpenseClaim', array('ExpenseClaim.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'))));
 }

My app users both the auth and the ACL comps could it be those? Kind of regretting learning cake now. This is crazy.

Comment: first - upvote my ansver :p  :) secound - see if codepage is ok, remove closing php `?>` from end of file if you have it... try to replace it with fresh/new controller and then copy the code... maybe it will be helpful...

Comment: Turns out, the issue was with App controller and me using JS rather than Js for the helper. I cant believe that caused a 500 though! Thank you for all your help/

Comment: Sometimes I've found that Cake will cause a 500 error if debugging is set to 0 but if you change it to 3 you'll get a much more detailed error which will be easier to debug. This might be worth trying if you get another 500 error in the future as it can save a lot of guesswork.